# Jsoup - unable to get node by class name

Tags: java, ajax, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrap this link: http://www.soccerbase.com/tournaments/tournament.sd?tourn_id=1159

but I sometimes get an empty collection with the following code:

```
String cur = http://www.soccerbase.com/tournaments/tournament.sd?tourn_id=1159;
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(cur).get();
Elements table = doc.getElementsByClass("soccerContent");
System.out.println(table);
```

The output is empty sometimes and I cannot figure out why. However, `doc.getElementsByTag("div")` works ALL THE TIME. So I'm wondering if `getElementsByClass` is broken?

I have set a 1 sec interval between requests and their `robots.txt` doesn't say anything about `user_agent`, so black listing shouldn't be a problem.

Clarification: the scraping is for a school project and is not for commercial use.

**EDIT:**

I found that the problem is, for some reason my requests get redirected to another page. If I open the page in browser first then send request, it will return the desired page without even attempting to redirect me. Can someone explain why this happens? Thanks!

I have hundreds of pages to crawl so manually open them one by one may not be the best option.

Comment: do the XHR request by yourself

Comment: @JEY Hey it turns out AJAX is not the issue. The website for some reason returns me a cached version. I've updated the description. Do you know why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Simply , add `Cache-Control, no-cache` and `Cache-Store, no-store` . Jsoup has `Connection` class and it provides to specify header for your requests. If it works, let me know.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut Thanks for the reply. I've added the headers but I haven't been able to test it because there has been another issue. Previously for those unvisited pages it just returns a cached page, but now it returns an empty page (only basic `html`, `head` and `body` tags). It behaves this way with or w/o the headers.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut Okay it behaves normal now...why it continuously returned empty page is still a mystery, but now it returns a page, but still in cached version. Here's my codeL `Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Cache-Control", "no-cache").header("Cache-Store", "no-store");`

Comment: Can you try to add `max-age=0` for Cache-Control.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut Hey, sorry I misunderstood what happened. I was actually get redirected to another page. The thing is I only get redirected if I have not visited the desired page in browser. If I set `followRedirect(false)`, it will return an empty page for unvisited pages.